# Bootstrap 3 - spacing issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building a simple form using Bootstrap in which I am facing some layout issues related to spacing. This is how the form looks like
[image: UI gap between rows]

1. There is lots of space between the label and fields. For instance, in the above image empty space between label and name field is highlighted. I would like to increase the width of input field so that the space reduces.
2. I would like to get rid of the vertical space between 2 fields. For instance, there is a space between author and IP fields. I would like them to be closed together. Again, not able to make out the reason.

[This is the fiddle I have created to reproduce  the problem.](https://jsfiddle.net/sbcobqz9/55/)

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.input-field {
  height: 20px
}

.custom-label {
  line-height: 3.3em !important;
}

.label-size {
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 2.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 label-size">Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="gender" class="col-md-4 label-size">Gender</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <select id="gender" class="form-control input-sm input-field label-size">
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 label-size custom-label">Functions</label>
        <div class="checkbox col-md-8 label-size checkbox-primary" >
          <label class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Func1"> Func1</label>
          <label class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Func2">Func2</label>
          <label class="col-md-3">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Func2">Func3</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="country" class="col-md-4 label-size">country</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <select id="country" class="form-control input-sm input-field label-size">
            <option>Select</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>1</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <label class="label-size">Options</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">

          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">
            <!-- there is a for loop here-->
            <!-- For every run of loop, one div [with col-xs-4] below will be created. Since loop is not there, I am creating multiple divs manually -->
            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>

          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary label-size col-md-3">

            <input id="check1" type="checkbox"> check1
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="addr" class="col-md-4 label-size">ADDR</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="addr" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="authro" class="col-md-4 label-size">authro</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="authro" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="range" class="col-md-4 label-size">Range</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" id="range" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          to
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <input type="text" id="range2" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ip" class="col-md-4 label-size">IP</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="ip" class="form-control input-sm input-field">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-10 ">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button class="btn btn-xs" type="button">Start</button>

        </div>

        <label class="col-xs-2 label-size">Order</label>

        <div class="radio" class="col-xs-4 label-size">

          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="order3">order3</label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="order4">order4</label>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
 




</form>

</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you provide me your exact jsfiddle url?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but to figure out if you have some rogue margins somewhere, you can use the google chrome inspect feature and hover over items with the mouse to see what is causing the issue. You can also edit the padding, etc, to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sbcobqz9/55/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some format changes to your `code` see if this fix your need.
http://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/sbcobqz9/66/

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
```

should fix your format/alignments

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fiddle. The space between 2 inputs fields is still the same. I would like to reduce the gap between 'Author' and 'IP' fields, for instance. Also, I don't want labels to be right aligned. Labels should still be left aligned but space between label and input element should be reduced by virtue of input element size being increased.

Comment: Are you talking about the size of the input fields? I'm not sure I understand what the gap between Author and IP is

Comment: Please refer to the attached screenshot. There is lots of empty space between 2 rows (highlighted in red). I want to reduce this gap so that 2 rows are closer to each other.

Comment: ): I can't open the img. I'll take a look when I'm on another computer

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ayang10/sbcobqz9/66/ I think this is what you're looking for. use update the  `.form-horizontal .form-group {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}`

Comment: Thank you very much. Please post it as a solution and I'll accept it as an answer.

Comment: I've edited my answer, so it should be correct now. (: